# Disabling or Removing the Dataannotation on pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a from which contains the button on clicking which i am populating a Window that contains two Input type Password inputs.I have used Validation on all inputs which is working so nicely now my problem is that when I am closing this window and again reopening it the Validation span remains there only.How to remove or disable this?
Please share the solution.
My code goes as follows:

```
 @model Invoice.Models.ViewModels.PasswordManagement.PasswordViewModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Auth", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal Password" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    New Password
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword)<br/>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OldPassword)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Confirm Password
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword)<br/>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassword)
                </div>
            </div>

            <center style="margin-left: 25px;">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" style="width:68px;" />
                <input type="button" class="k-button" id="PasswordWindowClose" value="Cancel" style="width:65px;" />
            </center>


        }
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#PasswordWindowClose").on('click', function () {
                $('#PasswordWindowClose').parents('.k-window-content').data('kendoWindow').close();
                var validator = $(".Password").data('validator');
                    validator.settings.ignore = "input[type=password]";
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this here i am adding it.

```
$('.input-validation-error').addClass('input-validation-valid');
$('.input-validation-error').removeClass('input-validation-error');
$('.field-validation-error').addClass('field-validation-valid');
$('.field-validation-error').removeClass('field-validation-error');
$('.validation-summary-errors').addClass('validation-summary-valid');
$('.validation-summary-errors').removeClass('validation-summary-errors');
```